# Paypal Subscription : Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am currently working with the setup of PayPal Subscription through REST API in sandbox environment.
I am able to add product, add plan and also add subcription with APIs.
But at the payment page ( on the PayPal side ), where it asks to click for subscription, error occurs.

Error occurs at the page: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions?ba_token=BA-0T473376T5204322K, when i hit the `Login to subscribe` button.

[Error Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLPeV.png)

When i check the console, here's the response that it triggers on the page:

**Request URL** : https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/api/billagmt/BA-0T473376T5204322K/createCart

**Headers**
`Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request`

**Response** 
`{"ack":"contingency","contingency":"VALIDATION_ERROR","meta":{"calc":"...some string...","rlog":"...some string.."},"server":"...some string..."}`

I am unable to do any kind of debug as it occurs over PayPal Page.
Kindly help me to find if what is going wrong at my side (i.e., API) ?

**My Code**

**API Call ( Add Subscription )**

```
$request = json_encode($req);
$header = [ 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->getOauthToken() ];
$method = 'POST';
$url = $this->paypal_url.'billing/subscriptions';
$response = json_decode($this->callAPI($header, $method, $request, $url));
```

**Helpers**

```
// Call API
private function callAPI($header, $method, $request, $url) 
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method) {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($request)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            if ($request)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);                               
            break;
        default:
            if ($request)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($request));
    }

    // OPTIONS:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    // EXECUTE:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    if(!$result){ die("Connection Failure"); }

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}

// Fetch Oauth Token
private function getOauthToken() 
{   
    $url = $this->paypal_url.'oauth2/token';
    $header = [ 
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($this->client_id.':'.$this->client_secret) 
    ];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    if(!$result) { die("Connection Failure"); } 

    curl_close($curl);

    $response = json_decode($result);
    return $response->access_token;
}
```

It gives me HATEOAS link like: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions?ba_token=BA-0T473376T5204322K, where the error occurs.

Also my data is complete OK as per API requirements.
Because i have already modified all possible errors regarding the data incompatibilty.

If it's complete description about problem, then please try to help me not by just triggering hold, but figuring out the issue.

Comment: If you need any other details just ask in order to resolve the problem.

Comment: It is complete unacceptable for me that someone just trigger hold inspite of describing my problem clearly in detail.

Comment: Hi there, you are getting this due to some issue in either paln or subscription's creation, to solve this, just take JSON payload from Paypal API docs, and put your data one by one, so you can get whats happening,

Comment: @SudhanshShekharDubey I agree with the harish comment. please check you subscription payload.  use this -> {
  "plan_id": "",
  "shipping_amount": {
    "currency_code": "GBP",
    "value": "0.00"
  },
  "application_context": {
    "brand_name": "Peerz Tutor",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "shipping_preference": "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
    "user_action": "SUBSCRIBE_NOW",
    "payment_method": {
      "payer_selected": "PAYPAL",
      "payee_preferred": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED"
    },
    "return_url": "",
    "cancel_url": ""
  }
}

Comment: Thanks manish and harish , I modified the payload data and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. Some subscription payments were going through and others not. The form payload looked the same.

When it was returning the error, we realised that the value for the number of times that subscription payments recur (`srt`) was set to 1. The docs point out that the minimum value shoudbe 2 and maximum of 52.